# image file Blocked and permission denied in nougat when take screenshot an activity

Tags: android, image, capture, mediastore

I m taking current Activity screenshot on OnClick button and share using intent chooser but permission denied in nougat and fail attachment and Calling permission request Oncreate method.

//Permission method

```
 private boolean checkAndRequestPermissions(){

int externalStoragePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,   Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();

    if (externalStoragePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    }
    if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mActivity, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), REQUEST_READ_PERMISSION);

        return false;
    }
    return true;

}
```

Here is Method of Take screenshot of an Activity/Specific Layout

```
      public void Share_result() {
    String uniqueId = getTodaysDate() + "_" + getCurrentTime() + "_" +   Math.random();

    Bitmap bitmap;
    View v = findViewById(R.id.snapview);
    mAdView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    bitmap = v.getDrawingCache();
    try {
        File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir(), uniqueId + ".png");

        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();

        file.setReadable(true, false);

        final Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Let me recommend you this application.\n https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.beaconites.gratuitycalculator ");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "UAE Gratuity Calculator");
        intent.setType("image/*");

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "choose one"));
        mAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
}
```

Comment: Which exception do a get? Look in the logcat! A `FileUriExposedException`? If not then change `getCacheDir()` by `getExternalCacheDir()`.

Comment: Thanks ..problem solved by getExternalCacheDir()